# Open pop-up window while HTML5 video is playing

Tags: javascript, html, video, popup, popcornjs

I'm using popcorn.js to provide some interactions with HTML5 video. While the video is playing, I'm trying to get another window (with another video) to open at a certain time point and then close x number of seconds later. Basically, I'm trying to recreate the functionality seen here: http://thewildernessdowntown.com

The issue I'm having is that my pop up window is being blocked by Firefox's pop-up blocker. How can I get around this? Again, I'll refer back to http://thewildernessdowntown.com because their windows open up fine, but I can't figure out what they're doing.

Here's some pretty basic code that I have:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var $popcorn = Popcorn('#video');

    $popcorn.code({
        start: 6,
        end: 12,
        onStart: function() {
            window.open('window.html','window','width=400,height=200');
        },
        onEnd: function() {
            window.close();
        }
    });

}, false );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can open a new window inside a 'click' event listener, but not inside a timeout or video timeupdate event, which is what Popcorn uses. But if you watch The Wilderness Downtown closely, it gets around that problem by opening several windows in advance when you click the start button and then re-using those windows later. So something like this...

```
document.getElementById('start-button').addEventListener('click', function() {

    var $popcorn = Popcorn('#video'),
        popup = window.open('about:blank','mywindow','width=10,height=10');

    $popcorn.code({
        start: 6,
        end: 12,
        onStart: function() {
            window.open('window.html','mywindow');
            popup.moveTo(400, 400);
            popup.resizeTo(400,200);
            popup.focus();
        },
        onEnd: function() {
            //window.close();
            /* in case you want to re-use this window again later... */
            window.open('about:blank','mywindow');
            popup.moveTo(0, 0);
            popup.resizeTo(10, 10);
        }
    });

    //optionally...
    $popcorn.play();

}, false );
```

You will run into problems if the window you're opening points to a different domain.